# JavaScript não é reconhecido pelo Chrome

Tags: javascript, java, aplicação-web, spring, google-chrome

Estou com problemas usando Spring MVC, Google Chrome e JavaScript.

Toda vez que eu crio um arquivo JavaScript novo, no meu projeto utilizando Spring, o browser não reconhece este arquivo.

Já limpei o cache, e não resolveu.

Comment: Não conheço nada de Spring, pode explicar melhor onde entra o JS, como ele está sendo incluído no HTML? É o HTML que no final vai dizer ao browser quais JS carregar.

Comment: Posta o código de como tá implementando o JS